# Javascript Change the Audio src

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, audio

I want to change the Audio `src` to listen other radio sources, but it doesn't change on android.  It does, however, change on my PC. On android the `src`, appears blank.

```
<form>
<p style="text-align: center"><font size="4"> Wähle dein Radio</font></p>
<select id="aSelectControl" data-theme="c">
<option></option>
<option onclick=" var player = document.getElementById('player'); player.src='http://mp3.stream.tb-group.fm/ht.mp3'; player.play();">HouseTime.FM</option>
<option onclick=" var player = document.getElementById('player'); player.src='http://mp3.stream.tb-group.fm/clt.mp3'; player.play();">Clubtime.FM </option>
<option onclick=" var player = document.getElementById('player'); player.src='http://80.237.157.79:80/iloveradio2.mp3'; player.play();">ILove2Dance </option>
</select>
</form>

 <audio id="player" controls="controls" src=""></audio>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what exactly you're seeking assistance with. Are you saying the audio source appears as blank on an android device?  It is possible to post the current code to see a demo of the issue?

Comment: http://kontex1.hol.es/radio.html here the demo
try it on your Pc and then on your Andriod device

Comment: This is what I see on my PC for the audio tag: `<audio id="player" controls="controls" src="">Wird Leider nicht unterstützt</audio>`  As you can see, the `src` is also empty.  I'm using Chrome to see the source code.  I also see the same thing on my Galaxy S3- using the Firefox View Source add-on.

Comment: yes at the beginning the src is nothing but if you click in the drop menu on a Radio station javascript say to the player the right src in
this part 

onclick=" var player = document.getElementById('player'); player.src='http://80.237.157.79:80/iloveradio2.mp3'; player.play();

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it may be a known issue based on this link:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10546

Looks like the `audio` tag may not be supported.

A work around to try would be to force the JavaScript to load the audio when you click on it using a `onclick` property

Comment: but if i put the source in i can play the radio station 

<audio id="player" controls="controls" src="http://80.237.157.79:80/iloveradio2.mp3"></audio>

Comment: Can we see the JavaScript code?  It's possible it may not be binding the source link to the `src`.

Comment: http://kontex1.hol.es/radio.html here i edited for you
if you now go on your andriod device you can play the radio but can't change it